# How to embed Youtube video in Cordova Android app

Tags: android, iframe, cordova, youtube

I am new to Cordova App development.

I have a Youtube URL and I want to embed the video in Cordova app. I have tried making it with YouTube Api(JS Library) and with iframe also. What do I have to do to make the video load on the Android app?

Comment: Were you able to figure out ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using iframe is the preferred and suggested way to embed youtube videos, so this is how you need to proceed. The getting started code from the [YoutTube iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) reference loads and works in both iOS (tested on iOS 7) and Android (tested on Android 4.3).

Comment: however, it won't work on android 2.3 or less i think.

Comment: have not tested myself, but it is possible since the WebView in Android 2.x was very basic.

Comment: I've tested on 4.3 and it was working, so if it ain't on your end, there must be something wrong. Please post some markup..

Comment: do you have any working example for youtube video inline and full screen playing?

Answer (score 20):

For me, the solution was editing `config.xml` file adding the following lines:

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />   
<allow-navigation href="*youtube*" />
<allow-navigation href="*ytimg*" />
<allow-navigation href="*youtube-nocookie*" />
```

Comment: Strangely *.youtube* and *.ytimg* didn't worked, had to remove the dots.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks

Comment: I did not need either of the `<preference>` elements listed here, but in addition to the two listed `<allow-navigation>` elements, I also needed `<allow-navigation href="*youtube-nocookie*" />`.

Comment: This fixed youtube iframe not loading in iOS devices but there's an important downside. Clicking the youtube logo overlay will let the user to navigate away from your app making it impossible to return to the original index.html. As a workaround I decided to use the InAppBrowser to load the iframe content. Just used the 2 preference lines.

Comment: @Lothre1 Can you provide more details about your workaround? The workaround I used was to replace the embed URL with https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/VIDEOIDHERE . In my testing, this makes tapping on the YouTube logo not do anything. You can also take it a step further and remove the YouTube logo entirely by replacing the embed URL with https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/VIDEOIDHERE?modestbranding=1

Answer (score 1):

Adding the parameter feature=player_embedded to the iframe url worked fine for me:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/*********?feature=player_embedded" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: is there any way to stop exit app on press back button while this video in fullscreen mode?

Comment: This does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using `<access origin="*" />` (not recommended) you will need to allow the following domains with your config.xml to embed youtube videos in an cordova android app:

```
<access origin="https://*.youtube-nocookie.com" />
<access origin="https://*.youtube.com" />
<access origin="https://*.ytimg.com" />
<access origin="https://*.gstatic.com" />
<access origin="https://*.googlevideo.com" />
<access origin="https://*.google.com" />
```

This is for use with the `privacy-enhanced` embed mode. The `youtube-nocookie` domain presumably is not needed for a standard embed.

If you use a content security meta tag you will also need to allow those domains in your csp.