# In Ionic Framework App playing youtube video in browser but not in android device

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

In a simple Ionic app I have to play a youtube video. It works fine in browser but not run on actual android device.
I referred to the code from http://plnkr.co/edit/XmyAhE?p=preview

I use the following code in my ionic app,

```
<ion-view view-title="{{navTitle}}">
    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
        <div class="list card">
            <div class="item item-divider">
                <i class="ion-videocamera"></i>
                Video
            </div>
            <div class="padding">
                <object width="100%" height="150">
                    <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/WzhW20hLp6M?version=3&amp;hl=uk_UA&amp;rel=0"></param>
                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param
                    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
                    <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/WzhW20hLp6M?version=3&amp;hl=uk_UA&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="150" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
                </object>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Here is browser output screen :**

[image]

**And output Screen In Android Device :**

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed Youtube video in Cordova Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488856/how-to-embed-youtube-video-in-cordova-android-app)

Comment: Hello Santosh Shinde, i work on news application in ionic platform so i want to load some youtube videos from JSON response and load in device. so can you give me some hint which control or plugin is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem using add plugin in my application

```
  cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

Comment: hi, can you specify how you do this, you go through the comman line to the root dir of the app and just run that command?

Comment: Yes , I go through the command line to the root dir of the app

Comment: I installed this, but still no video on the device, just in the browser.

Comment: you are facing problem in browser or device , please specify your codepen.

Comment: And u can also add Whitelist by add this line 

`.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) 
{
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', new RegExp('^(http[s]?):\/\/(w{3}.)?youtube\.com/.+$')]);
})`

Answer (score 2):

Consider using an iframe in place of `<object></object`.  Here are the [instructions on how to get the iframe from a youtube video](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en).  The upside of using the iframe method is if the browser supports html5, it will use html5 to play the video.  It also supports various other methods of playback if the web browser supports it.  Here is some [further reading on youtube video playback](https://www.youtube.com/html5).

Comment: Yea, same. I used iframe API, there are restricted playback on certain videos. Any idea how to solve it?