# Embed youtube video in visual studio tool for cordova

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, youtube, visual-studio-2015

I am a new at cordova visual studio. I want to embed or import youtube video in my android application in Visual Studio tool for cordova 2015. But it is not show any video when I run my code. Below is the code.

```
    <div id="player">
        <iframe id="player" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sGPrx9bjgC8" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="play">Play</a>||
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="pause">Pause</a>||
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="mute">Mute</a>||
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="unmute">UnMute</a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>-->
</body>
```

Here is an image when I run my code.
[image]

Comment: Which platform are you using? Only windows phone? Please, check the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39175751/2765346

Comment: Android and Ripple-Galaxy Nexus

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to install [cordova-whitelist-plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) if you don't have it.

In your HTML file, you have to include the following meta tag. It allows iframe to Youtube.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com/">
```

Also, you can use a tag that allows everything:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

And at the end you need to add `<access>` tags in your `config.xml` file:

```
<access origin="https://www.youtube.com" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the domain youtube.com in your config.xml with property "iframe" set to "true"

```
<allow-navigation href="https://youtube.com" iframe="true" />
```

Comment: be carrefull there is 2 same "id" : id="player"  , can you copy your logs please

Comment: without your logs, i can not help you, please post your console logs and if possible visual studio logs

Comment: Here is my console log.


Console was cleared
ripple.js:37 Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Grey. Hot.)
ripple.js:37 cordova :: Setting the user agent server side failed.
ripple.js:37 cordova :: Your application does not appear to match the platform you have selected. The version number in your configuration might not match the selected platform version or your configuration file has errors in it.
_log @ ripple.js:37
ripple.js:37 cordova :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.)